# How to make my own new Ubuntu based operating system?

Tags: customization, software-sources, open-source, uck

I want to make my own new Ubuntu based operating system.
With New custom theme and lot of softwares pre-built !
Can I do it only with UCK (Ubuntu Customization Kit) ?
Then how ?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/48535/how-to-customize-the-ubuntu-live-cd

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCDCustomization

Comment: Thank you for the help @the_Seppi 
But my problem is that I don't know much codes to do it.
I just know to install packages, update, and wget !
Then how ?